# Rails3 records this year

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date, where-clause

In Rails3 how do I retrieve all records that have a date of this year? 
I'd like to retrieve all my "Projects" where the "date" is this year.

I would suspect it would be something similar to:

```
@projects_this_year = Project.where(:date.Time.year == Time.now.year)
or
@projects_this_year = Project.where(:date >= ?, Time.now.year)
```

I'm reading through the docs, but haven't quite figured this out yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this (Assuming a MySQL DB):

`@projects_this_year = Project.where("year(date) = ?", Time.now.year)`

or better:

`@projects_this_year = Project.where("year(date) = year(utc_timetamp())")`

which doesn't require loading the time library.

For reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Edit

---

If you want it to be database independent then you can do something like this:

`@projects_this_year = Project.where("date >= ?", Time.now.at_beginning_of_year)`

Comment: +1 for the extra info. We would like to keep our app database independent right now as still in dev and not sure of which for production yet. Thanks

Comment: The accepted answer is wrong, in addition to syntax issues it will return true for any date because you are comparing the integer value of the date (something like 1337850045) with DateTime.now.year (2012). See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make this dynamic in the model if you needed specific months or years often or through params by expanding on @David's answer:

```
def self.get_year(date)
    # sanitize if params
    safe = ['2011', '2012', '2013']
    if safe.include?(date)
         where("year(created_at) = ?", Time.parse("#{date}-01-01 11:11:11 -0500").year)
    else
         scoped
    end
end
```

EX:

```
Product.get_year('2012')
```

*NOTE to get this to work on heroku please change the following:*

```
where("date_part('year', created_at) = ?", Time.parse("#{date}-01-01 11:11:11 -0500").year
```

http://www.java2s.com/Code/PostgreSQL/Date-Timezone/datepartyeardate.htm